# Expected nested-name-specifier before ‘namespace’

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a basic program to add 2 binary strings. Given two binary strings a and b, add them together and return the resulting string.
I am compiling it with a C++ compiler (G++ v8.4.0)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std; 

std::string addBinaryStrings(std:: string a, std:: string b) 
{ 
    std::string result = ""; 
    int s = 0;         

    int i = a.size() - 1, j = b.size() - 1; 
    while (i >= 0 || j >= 0 || s == 1) 
    { 
        s += ((i >= 0)? a[i] - '0': 0); 
        s += ((j >= 0)? b[j] - '0': 0); 
         result = char(s % 2 + '0') + result; 
        s /= 2; 
        i--; j--; 
    } 
    return result; 
} 
int main() 
{ 
    string a,b;
    getline(cin, a);
    getline(cin, b);
    cout << addBinaryStrings(a, b) << endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```

When I execute this I get the following error :

```
main.cpp online 2:7: error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘namespace’
 using namespace std;
       ^~~~~~~~~
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your program compiles fine. But read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: As can be seen [here](https://godbolt.org/z/E19zbj), there's nothing wrong with the code you've posted. So you're doing something wrong but it's not the code.

Comment: Taking a guess, are you compiling C++ code as C? More details of exactly what you are doing are needed, because it's not the code.

Comment: @john I am compiling it with a C++ compiler (G++ v8.4.0)

Comment: So, more details, what command line are you using?

Comment: @john I am not really sure about that.

Comment: So **describe what you are doing**. Clearly you aren't typing commands on the command line. Are you using an IDE? Just say what you did immediately before you saw this error message.

Comment: Clearly the problem here is that you are using your compiler incorrectly. But without any details about how you are using your compiler it's impossible to say what is wrong.

Comment: @john I am using an IDE, i am doing all of this online in a VSCode Editor.

Comment: @ITsme OK the notorious VSCode. Almost certainly you have set it up incorrectly. If you can't figure it out for yourself, then you need to post the details of your various configuration files, so people who know a bit about VSCode will be able to advise.

Comment: @ITsme But my advice would be to find something easier to use than VSCode.

Comment: @john Thanks buddy, will do.

Comment: @ITsme Wait `online` I missed that. Can you post a link to the web site you are using.

Comment: @john https://app.codesignal.com/

Comment: @ITsme So there doesn't seem to be any way I can try that out for myself without going through a whole load of tutorials. All I can advise is that somehow you are using the website incorrectly. But exactly how I can't say.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing wrong with this code as its working on my C++ GNU compiler.
So there is something wrong with your compiler. I suggest you to reset settings of your compiler or use another compiler. You can also use online IDE.